# FullCalendar sync with Google Calendar - Permissions

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I have looked everywhere.

I am trying to integrate full calendar with google calendar using [this webpage](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/). On the first step, it asks you to get a Google API Key. I got my API key, and after following all of the steps, I received nothing. After I went back to my API Console, it displayed:

[image]

So, I went on to create credentials. On the creation page, it displayed this:[image]

I used the user data option, and it did not work. What shall I do?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css'/>
<script src='fullcalendar/lib/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script type='fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        googleCalendarApiKey: '<API-KEY>',
        events: {
            googleCalendarId: '<CALENDAR-ID>'
        }
    });
});

</script>
</html>
```

I did make sure my calendar was public and "Share only my free/busy information" is unchecked. LMK if you need any other additional info.

[UPDATE]
I clicked on "If you wish you can skip this step and create an" API key on the credentials page, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to add `<div id='calendar'></div`> to the body of my html file. I feel incredibly stupid.

For any of you looking for some example code, here it is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css'/>
        <script src='fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js'"></script>
        <script src='fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
        <script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    googleCalendarApiKey: '<API-KEY>',
                    events: {
                        googleCalendarId: '<CALENDAR-ID>'
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='calendar'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Follow all of the other steps mentioned in the question, and you should be good to go!

Also remember to link your file paths correctly, like @Lahiru said.

Sorry for the confusion,

Ujjwal

Answer (score 0):

correct the .js path `<script src='/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>`

remove the SLASH(/)

it should be like `<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>`

Comment: Hi @Lahiru, I updated my code with the right file paths after I posted this question. There are no errors being thrown about wrong file paths. All of the functions seem to be working as well. Yet, I get a blank page and console every single time!